# What happens if two guests in WestWorld want to do the same thing during their stay?

Tags: westworld-2016

In the universe of the show, WestWorld is one of the most luxurious vacation/resort/theme parks in the world.

It caters to the ultra-rich, who desire immersion past that which Virtual Reality can offer.

For an *exorbitant* price, your (Cowboy/Shogun/Safari/etc.) fantasy can come true. You will be catered to, and most importantly: ***You will be free to do whatever you want during your stay.***

The format for WestWorld can be compared to a highly streamlined RPG. NPCs (Hosts) exist in the world, some of which offer quests for the player (guest) to pursue. Some of these little side-quests that we see in the show are things like finding a treasure, going on a walk to a scenic area, or even hunting down a dangerous bounty.

We *also* know that the WestWorld experience, while offering a ton of replayability, runs on a loop and only *really* changes with narrative updates, which are implied to be a rather big deal, like an expansion pack or major content patch.

Now, to get to my question.

In an episode of the first season, a guest recognizes Teddy from a previous visit.

The guest implies that Teddy is a start point for a (possibly several) entertaining side-quests, or at the very least, a good Host to have as a guide to *find* fun stuff. So, people are coming back with a desire to **repeat specific experiences from previous visits**.

Now: **What would happen if two guests wanted to participate in the same activities with the same host, but did not want to share company?**

Could I show up to WestWorld and Teddy is just gone? Already off on some adventure with another Guest?

What if I want to go bounty hunting with the sheriff, but I don't want to go with this other group of Guests I don't know?

For example: **William is with Dolores on their adventure for several days. What if another guest's main reason for their visit was for the specific experience of Dolores and her associated loops?**

Is their stay just ruined? A voucher for another trip?

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple active Teddys in duplicate zones? Or is there only 1 of each zone and only 1 active version of each Host?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is really answerable with any certainty, but I have worked in hospitality dealing with guests who make specific requests, and those are normally communicated beforehand. So, basically, if I wanted to do something specific, I'd make a reservation. In case of a double-booking, it's first-come, first served. 
If this became common enough to cause the business to lose money, it doesn't seem like it would be too hard to identify the more popular narratives and stagger those experiences over time for the guests. You could have several Teddys in identical storylines running concurrently, using the resources like the town or bar only when not being used by other identical narratives. (It's a bit analogous to a multi-threaded application in computers). Of course, you'd have to be smart about not crossing the stories. But, the hosts do a lot to drive the story forward, so they could just "subconsciously" know not to go where their counterparts are using the peer-to-peer mesh network they use for silent communication. No doubt managing this complexity would not be easy, but it is certainly possible and we have models for how it could work.